# OpenCV scalar used with template programming causes compilation error

Tags: c++, opencv, templates

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with the latest OpenCV from trunk and gcc 5.4.

I am having some trouble to understand why the below code cannot be compiled

```
template <typename T>
void Func2(const cv::Scalar clr, cv::Mat &img){
  img.at<T>(0, 0) = clr;
}

void Func1(const bool flag, const cv::Scalar clr, cv::Mat &img){
  if (flag == 1){
    Func2<cv::Vec4b>(clr, img);
  }
  else{
    Func2<cv::Vec3b>(clr, img);
  }
}

int main(){
  cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(100, 100, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(1,1,1,1));
  cv::Scalar clr = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0);

  Func1(1, clr, img);

  return 0;
}
```

The compilation error is

> In instantiation of `void Func2(cv::Scalar, cv::Mat&) [with T =
>   cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>; cv::Scalar = cv::Scalar_<double>]`: required from here
>
> error: no match for `operator=` (operand types are `cv::Vec<unsigned
>   char, 3>` and `const Scalar {aka const cv::Scalar_<double>}`)
>   `img.at<T>(0, 0) = clr;
>                      ^`
>
> /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp:305:38: note: candidate:
>   `constexpr cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>& cv::Vec<unsigned char,
>   3>::operator=(const cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>&)  template<typename
>   _Tp, int cn> class Vec : public Matx<_Tp, cn, 1>
>                                         ^` 
>  /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/matx.hpp:305:38: note:   no known
>   conversion for argument 1 from `const Scalar {aka const
>   cv::Scalar_<double>}` to `const cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>&`

I was thinking it might be that the type of `cv::Scalar` needs to be matched up correctly but even the below code compiles without a problem

```
int main(){
  cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(100, 100, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(1,1,1,1));
  cv::Scalar clr = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0);

  img.at<cv::Vec4b>(0, 0) = clr // still compiles but has runtime error

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it this way since Scalar has different number of dimensions than your mat and the operator = is not resolved in such the case. It's best explained by this inheritance diagram from OpenCV documentation:

### [image]

As you can see, scalar is a 4 dimensional vector with template type, while each element in your mat is always 1 dimension, but different number of channels denoted as cn. You need to assign the value to each Mat element explicitly using cv::Scalar::operator[] to access each channel separately.

Comment: The last code snippet I showed it actually compiles despite the dimension mismatch with Scalar and Mat. Do you know why?

Comment: In your last snippet it's ok as you are assigning Scalar (which is 4 dims) to Vec4b passed in template to Mat (which results in 4 chanels). Anyway, what is happening is that you are assigning Scalar (4 channel) to Vec4b (also 4 channel) so everything works fine.

Comment: I guess I am mixing up the definitions of dims and channels, I thought they are the same thing. So in the last snippet there are 3 channels in the scalar and 4 channels in the mat and it still compiles. Could you let me know the definition of dimensions in OpenCV?

Comment: Even if you use cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0) constructor, the Scalar still has 4 dimensions internally. All that matters in your case is what you have in Mat::at<T> template and what you have on the right hand side of the = symbol. As I said earlier, Scalar is compatible with Vec4b because it has the same number of dimensions and in fact it inherits from vector.
The number of channels in cv::Mat depends on the type you create it with in constructor (i.e. CV_8UC3 resolves to 3 channels, 1 dim). A more detailed description is here:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html